# Spring Data vs Couchbase SDK

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase

What is the difference between Spring Data Library and Couchbase Java SDK? Is one preferred over the other in specific scenarios? If I am working on Spring project , is Spring Data preferred over Couchbase Java SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data helps you create automatic Data Access Objects based on entity definitions. It works with multiple types of data stores.

So, you could write your own DAOs to insert/update/delete/select items from couchbase, or you could let Spring Data do it for you.

Also, if you need to switch data stores later, your data access interfaces wouldn't change.

Comment: You don't really have to choose one OR the other as Spring Data Couchbase includes the SDK.